# A proof that $3D_{2m+1} \equiv 2 \pmod{3}$

Tags: number-theory

We consider the following definition of "new" numbers $D_m.$ We define them by the generating function

$$G(t) = \frac{-t}{e^t + 1 + e^{-t}} = \sum_{m \geq 0} D_m \frac{t^m}{m!}$$

The first part of the question was to compute the values of $D_m$ for $0 \leq m \leq 5.$ I did this correctly, the corresponding values are: $D_0 = 0, D_1 = -\frac{1}{3}, D_2 = 0, D_3 = \frac{2}{3}, D_4 = 0, D_5 = - \frac{10}{3}.$

The second part of the question was showing that $D_m = 0$ if $m$ is even. This is obvious as $G(t)$ is an odd function so all the even terms in its Taylor expansion will vanish.

The third question is to find a recursive formula for $D_m,$ we eventually get for $l = 2m + 1, m \geq 1$ that $$D_{2m+1} = - \frac{2}{3} \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \binom{2m+1}{2k+1}D_{2k+1}.$$

The final part of the question is showing that the denominator is always 3 and that the numerator is always 2 mod 3. My attempt is as follows:

I attempt a proof by induction: Let $m \geq 1,$ assume that for $D_{2k+1}$ with $0 \leq k \leq m-1$ we have $D_{2k+1} \equiv \frac{1}{3}A_{2k+1}$ with $A_{2k+1} \equiv 2 \pmod{3}$. If we also write $D_{2m+1} = \frac{1}{3}A_{2m+1}$ then $$A_{2m+1} = 2 \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \binom{2m+1}{2k+1}D_{2k+1} = \frac{2}{3}\left(\binom{2m+1}{1}A_1 + \binom{2m+1}{3}A_3 + \ldots + \binom{2m+1}{2m-1}A_{2m-1}\right) = 2 + 3l.$$ To show that the denominator is 3 we need to show that $A_{2m+1}$ is always an integer, or in other words, $3A_{2m+1} \equiv 0 \pmod{3}.$ To show that the numerator is congruent to 2 modulo 3 we need to show that $A_{2m+1} \equiv 2 \pmod{3}.$ Let's consider first the first congruence modulo 3: $$3A_{2m+1} = 2\left(\binom{2m+1}{1}A_1 + \binom{2m+1}{3}A_3 + \ldots + \binom{2m+1}{2m-1}A_{2m - 1}\right) \equiv \binom{2m+1}{1} + \binom{2m+1}{3} + \ldots + \binom{2m+1}{2m-1} =: B.$$ Using the binomial theorem $$2^{2m+1} = \binom{2m+1}{0} + \binom{2m+1}{1} + \ldots + \binom{2m+1}{2m+1} = B + \sum_{k=0}^{m} \binom{2m+1}{2k} + \binom{2m+1}{2m+1} = 1 + B + \sum_{k=0}^{m} \binom{2m+1}{2m + 1 - (2k+1)} = 1 + B + \sum_{k=0}^{m} \binom{2m+1}{2k+1} = 2 + 2B,$$ and therefore $B = 2^{2m} - 1,$ from which we conclude that $B \equiv (-1)^{2m} - 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$ which shows the conjecture about the denominator.

My issue is with proving the other fact, i.e., $A_{2m+1} \equiv 2 \pmod{3}$. I thought about trying to prove it mod 9 but it wasn't seeming to work, or trying $3A_{2m+1}$ again, but I didn't really know where to go from there. Any help?

Comment: I don't know how helpful this is, but your numbers are essentially Glaisher's G numbers: https://oeis.org/A002111 .  (I agree with your assessment that the induction you've started doing won't work unless you can strengthen it to capture all powers of 3, and that seems unlikely.  But another representation of your numbers might yield more.)

Comment: Assuming $-\frac{t}{e^t+e^{-t}+1}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} a(2 k+1)\, t^{2 k+1}$ and $\frac{1}{2 \cos\left(\sqrt{t}\right)+1}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} b(k)\, t^k$, I believe $a(2 k+1)=(-1)^{k+1}\, b(k)$. (see OEIS entries [A279120](https://oeis.org/A279120) and [A279121](https://oeis.org/A279121)), but I'm not sure if this observation is useful.